# Heterogeneous Development Environments

Tags: android, eclipse, shared-libraries

I have a mix of Linux and Windows development environments.  When I include an external JAR file as a library I have issues with the paths to such.

I want to have some commonalities between my projects rather than dictate what my developer must use as their OS.

How have you guys solved this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've successfully used Eclipse to develop Android apps in Windows, Linux and Mac OS, reusing the project files between each OS.  You would need to encode your path names as "Classpath Variables" in the IDE.  Here is one of many articles talking about how to set that up: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=367962.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Well, perfectly once I got the correct JARs in both places.  It would seem that Google updated the AdMob JAR since my original installation ;)  Thanks Tony.

Answer (score 0):

Use Maven, which stores all the references in a repository, and references them via logical names (group/artifact IDs), or store the jars in your project tree, and reference them with relative paths.